# how to make rails console does not show me the sqlite consult

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Hello friends I want to ask them how to make rails console 
does not show me the sqlite consult

```
Loading development environment (Rails 4.0.5)
2.0.0-p481 :001 > last_user=User.last
User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" ORDER BY "users"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
=> #<User id: 5, name: "Juan", email: "Lopez", created_at: "2014-06-02 19:50:48",      updated_at: "2014-06-02 19:50:48">
```

I do not want to show this

```
User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" ORDER BY "users"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In console type:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.logger = nil
```

Comment: As I return to active

Comment: You can reenable it with `ActiveRecord::Base.logger = Rails.logger`